# Declare new height and width for every new page on added jspdf using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, jspdf

```
var doc = new jsPDF('px','px', [388, 2401]); 
var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth;
var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight;
doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0, width, height);
doc.addPage();
doc.addImage(img1, 'JPEG', 0, 0, new_width, new_height); // another image 
doc.save("gg.pdf");
```

How can I re assign new width and height for every new image on jspdf as new `jsPDF('px','px', [388, 2401]);` only works for first image any way to do so that I can set new width and height for every image I add to pdf? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We seem to agree that px appears to be applied as 54 per inch

```
// We must declare 1st page canvas before use "p", is for portrait then default units , [size x, size y] 
var doc = new jsPDF("p", "px", [388, 2401]); 
var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth;
var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight;
doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0, width, height);

// oddly the order for new page is reversed, so size, then orientation
doc.addPage([new_width, new_height], "p");
doc.addImage(img1, 'JPEG', 0, 0, new_width, new_height); // another image
 
doc.save("gg.pdf");
```

However always check the scaling these 2 should be same units just rotated, they report same dimension and appearance of difference is perhaps an illusion. Same file, facing pages, one pane set as MangaMode

[image]